# Extra request on Uploadify initialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I'm using uploadify with MVC 3. When loading the page I have extra request to the page action - so many as uploadify units on the page.
How to tell uploadify not to do that?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same thing in a Ruby Sinatra app I built.  Dug into it a bit and realized that swfUpload was looking for a button image at the wrong url. I got it to work correctly by initializing the swfUpload button_image_url property to the Uploadify settings.buttonImage property:

```
var swfUploadSettings = {
    assume_success_timeout   : settings.successTimeout,
    button_placeholder_id    : settings.id,
    button_width             : settings.width,
    button_height            : settings.height,
    button_image_url  : settings.buttonImage,
    button_text              : null,
    ....
```

See also this comment in the Uploadify forums:
http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/comment/16999